# How to know if twitch streamer is live and send message about that? Discord.py

Tags: api, discord, discord.py, twitch, twitch-api

I'm writing discord bot now, so I wanted to know how to save the name of the streamer in a separate file, so when he goes live bot sends a message about that in specific channel.

This is what I tried:

```
import os
import json
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from twitchAPI.twitch import Twitch
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

Authentication with twitch API:

```
client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
client_secret = os.getenv('Dweller_token')
twitch = Twitch(client_id, client_secret)
twitch.authenticate_app([])
TWITCH_STREAM_API_ENDPOINT_V5 = "https://api.twitch.tv/dweller/streams/{}"
API_HEADERS = {
  'Client-ID': client_id,
  'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
}
```

Returns True if online, False if not:

```
def checkuser(user):
    try:
        userid = twitch.get_users(logins=[user])['data'][0]['id']
        url = TWITCH_STREAM_API_ENDPOINT_V5.format(userid)
        try:
            req = requests.Session().get(url, headers=API_HEADERS)
            jsondata = req.json()
            if 'stream' in jsondata:
                if jsondata['stream'] is not None:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error checking user: ", e)
            return False
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

Bot event. Always checks if streamer is live. Sends a message if so. And adds specific role to the streamer if he is live:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Defines a loop that will run every 10 seconds (checks for live users every 10 seconds).
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def live_notifs_loop():
        # Opens and reads the json file
        with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
            streamers = json.loads(file.read())
        # Makes sure the json isn't empty before continuing.
        if streamers is not None:
            # Gets the guild, 'twitch streams' channel, and streaming role.
            guild = bot.get_guild(1234567890)
            channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890)
            role = get(guild.roles, id=1234567890)
            # Loops through the json and gets the key,value which in this case is the user_id and twitch_name of
            # every item in the json.
            for user_id, twitch_name in streamers.items():
                # Takes the given twitch_name and checks it using the checkuser function to see if they're live.
                # Returns either true or false.
                status = checkuser(twitch_name)
                # Gets the user using the collected user_id in the json
                user = bot.get_user(int(user_id))
                # Makes sure they're live
                if status is True:
                    # Checks to see if the live message has already been sent.
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                        # If it has, break the loop (do nothing).
                        if str(user.mention) in message.content and "is now streaming" in message.content:
                            break
                        # If it hasn't, assign them the streaming role and send the message.
                        else:
                            # Gets all the members in your guild.
                            async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                                # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and
                                # they're live, give them the streaming role.
                                if member.id == int(user_id):
                                    await member.add_roles(role)
                            # Sends the live notification to the 'twitch streams' channel then breaks the loop.
                            await channel.send(
                                f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.mention} is now streaming on Twitch!"
                                f"\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}")
                            print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                            break
                # If they aren't live do this:
                else:
                    # Gets all the members in your guild.
                    async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                        # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and they're not
                        # live, remove the streaming role.
                        if member.id == int(user_id):
                            await member.remove_roles(role)
                    # Checks to see if the live notification was sent.
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                        # If it was, delete it.
                        if str(user.mention) in message.content and "is now streaming" in message.content:
                            await message.delete()
    # Start your loop.
    live_notifs_loop.start()
```

Command that adds 'chosen' streamers to json file:

```
# Command to add Twitch usernames to the json.
@bot.command(name='addtwitch', help='Adds your Twitch to the live notifs.', pass_context=True)
async def add_twitch(ctx, twitch_name):
    # Opens and reads the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
        streamers = json.loads(file.read())
    
    # Gets the users id that called the command.
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    # Assigns their given twitch_name to their discord id and adds it to the streamers.json.
    streamers[user_id] = twitch_name
    
    # Adds the changes we made to the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(streamers))
    # Tells the user it worked.
    await ctx.send(f"Added {twitch_name} for {ctx.author} to the notifications list.")

print('Server Running')
bot.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

I want to write '$add_twitch turb4ik' and bot saves streamer turb4ik in streamers.json and checks if streamer is live or not. If True send notification in specific channel. But it doesn't seem to work.

And I get this syntax error:

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'live_notifs_loop'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 62, in live_notifs_loop
    streamers = json.loads(file.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "add_twitch" is not found
```

I also tried this piece of code, it gives me the information about the channel, but it doesn't give me streamer status:

```
client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
oauth_token = os.getenv('Dweller_token')

twitch = Twitch(client_id, oauth_token)
twitch.authenticate_app([])

user_info = twitch.get_users(logins=['turb4ik'])
user_id = user_info['data'][0]['id']

print(user_info)
```

And there is one more problem: every time I start my bot it says that twitchAPI is not installed and I need to install it every time I start my bot. Sometimes my bot seems to forget about twitchAPI and goes offline and says that I again need to install twitchAPI.

I know this is hard, but please help me. Maybe I should do it witch SQL(sqlite3 library) or so. Much obliget!

Edit:
Another syntax error:

```
    Unhandled exception in internal background task 'live_notifs_loop'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 78, in live_notifs_loop
    streamers = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Ignoring exception in command addtwitch:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 136, in add_twitch
    streamers = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'live_notifs_loop'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 62, in live_notifs_loop
    streamers = json.loads(file.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Instead of `streamers = json.loads(file.read())` use `streamers = json.load(file)`

> `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "add_twitch" is not found`

Since you are defining your command with `name=addtwitch` agrument, you can only call your command with `$addtwitch user`. To avoid this, add the `aliases =['add_twitch']` argument to

> `@bot.command(name='addtwitch', help='Adds your Twitch to the live notifs.', pass_context=True, aliases =['add_twitch'])`

---

Comment: Thank, but I get another syntax error. I edited my question above.

Comment: I edited my question with new syntax error down below, can you take a look?

Comment: That's because you haven't edited `streamers = json.loads(file.read())` to `streamers = json.load(file)` @Dweller

Comment: sorry. I changed streamers `async def live_notifs_loop():` and in `async def add_twitch(ctx, twitch_name):` , but I still get errors